# Packing a DLL into an exe and deleting it after running

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to pack a dynamic link library (D L L) into an executable and when I run it I want it to be deleted from the hard drive.

so the first question i need help with is: How to PROPERLY add a D L L into my project? so when i build it, the D L L is in the executable?

and the second question is: once the D L L is properly included in the project & the project is build into an executable, i want the D L L to be injected to another process from the executable using the following code:

pastebin.com/zsYVMqvs

and now to the third question: once the D L L is injected & it has to be extracted somewhere right? so i would like to delete the extracted D L L instantly after injecting so it does not stay there.

Comment: The DLL doesn't get extracted at all. You need to write the code that extracts the DLL from the resources yourself.

Comment: If you don't want a DLL you can use a static library. It will become part of your executable.

Comment: You also could distribute the DLL with the executable. Maybe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you _actually_  trying to achieve? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Please try and make the question a bit more clear. Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also provide some clarification on why you want to embded the DLL instead of using a static library and what do you mean by remove? If the dll gets loaded in a second process then it will be write-protected so you can't remove it- You'll need to load it from a second location.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind- there's no big difference between an exe and dll from A PE perspective - you can just load your exe in a second process and export functions from it.

Comment: Please don't post links to code, but post the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the DLL into the resources of your .exe is a possibility. You then need to extract the DLL from the resources to a dll file on the local hard drive, probably into the temp directory. Then use it. Before the program quits, delete the dll created beforehand.

To extract use [FindResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ch/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea), [LoadResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx), [LockResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SizeofResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048(v=vs.85).aspx) .

Flow of operations:

1. Extract the DLL to the TEMP directory (use [GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppath))
2. run program doing whatever stuff you want to do with the DLL
3. befor the program quit make sure the DLL isn't used any more
4. delete the dll created under 1.